# Remove Directory function access denied

Tags: c++, file, visual-c++, mfc, permission-denied

I am using the c++ code below to delete temporary files from a specific path.

> C:\Users\falcon\AppData\Local\Temp\~GPG.TMP\

When inside the ~GPG.TMP folder exists some files, it deletes first and finally, it removes the folder itself. In this final step `RemoveDirectory(sPathName)` while I don't get any exceptions the folder is not actually deleted but when I am trying to access it (either externally or programmatically) I receive Error No 13 which is "Permission denied". Why does this happen?

```
void CFileOperation::DoDelete(CString sPathName)
{
    CFileFind ff;
    CString sPath = sPathName;

    if (CheckPath(sPath) == PATH_IS_FILE)
    {
        if (!CanDelete(sPath)) 
        {
            m_bAborted = true;
            return;
        }
        if (!DeleteFile(sPath)) throw new CFExeption(GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    PreparePath(sPath);
    sPath += "*.*";

    BOOL bRes = ff.FindFile(sPath);

    while(bRes)
    {
        bRes = ff.FindNextFile();
        if (ff.IsDots()) continue;
        if (ff.IsDirectory())
        {

            sPath = ff.GetFilePath();
            DoDelete(sPath);
        }
        else DoDelete(ff.GetFilePath());
    }
    ff.Close();

    if (!RemoveDirectory(sPathName) && !m_bAborted) {

        throw new CFExeption(GetLastError());


    }

}
```

Comment: Once your program is finished, can you delete C:\Users\falcon\AppData\Local\Temp\~GPG.TMP\ manually with the explorer?

Comment: @jabberwocky yes that's true and the folder can also be deleted in other steps of the running application before this exits.

Comment: _"when I am trying to access it"_, please show the relevant code. Show a [mcve]

Comment: 1) creating a new file inside or 2) debug pause just after the deletion and access with file explorer from Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According MSDN:
The `RemoveDirectory` function marks a directory for deletion on close. Therefore, the directory is not removed until the last handle to the directory is closed.

And, imho, Error 13 is `ERROR_INVALID_DATA`.

Comment: You mean that I may have open handles that should be closed?

Comment: The error 13 occurs when I am trying to create a new file just after the folder deletion since my app detects that the folder exists and is trying to create a new file inside without folder recreation (new temp file in progress)

Comment: I mean, that there are open handles (in same process or in other processes (explorer, etc)) that should be closed by handle owners (not your application). So, You can't control it.

Comment: Yes I understand, I suppose I can do nothing for that, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you can do nothing for that.